How does ld decide the alignment of a section?
I crosscompile for cortex M microcontroller using arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi
The .bss has 2KB alignment
objdump:
Idx Name              Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn  Flags
[...]
  6 .data             0000354c  20001000  3008f614  00091000  2**3  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  7 .dataNonCacheable 00000000  20000d00  20000d00  00094550  2**3  CONTENTS
  8 .data_OCRAM       00000000  20200000  20200000  00094550  2**0  CONTENTS
  9 .bss              00033d3c  20004800  20004800  00000800  2**11  ALLOC
 10 .bssNonCacheable  00000d00  20000000  20000000  00001000  2**6  ALLOC
 11 .bss_OCRAM        00029558  20200000  20200000  00001000  2**3  ALLOC
[...]

readelf:
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
[...]
  [ 7] .data             PROGBITS        20001000 091000 00354c 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 8] .dataNonCacheable PROGBITS        20000d00 094550 000000 00   W  0   0  8
  [ 9] .data_OCRAM       PROGBITS        20200000 094550 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [10] .bss              NOBITS          20004800 000800 033d3c 00  WA  0   0 2048
  [11] .bssNonCacheable  NOBITS          20000000 001000 000d00 00  WA  0   0 64
  [12] .bss_OCRAM        NOBITS          20200000 001000 029558 00  WA  0   0  8
  [13] .textFlash        PROGBITS        30002348 003348 0627c8 00  AX  0   0  8
[...]

However, my linker script does not enforce such an alignment:
    .bss : ALIGN(8)
    {
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4) ;
    } > SRAM_DTC

so I suspected it was the compiler that puts a minimum alignment of 2KB. However, I analyzed every .o file without finding any .o that has .bss with alignment higher than 1:
for f in `find FW/build/ -type f -name *.o` ;do echo $f; /opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-readelf -S -W $f; done | grep " .bss " | awk '{ if ($NF > 1) print $0 }'

so it has to be the linker arbitrarily deciding on the 2KB alignment.
I would like to understand why and how to avoid this
EDIT 2024-08-30
I modified the command line because the previous one didn't work:
for f in `find FW/build/ -type f -name *.o
do
    echo $f
    /opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-readelf -S -W $f
done | grep " .bss" | \
    awk 'strtonum($6) > 0 {print $NF, $0}' | \
    sort -n | \
    cut -d' ' -f2-

so I found the variable that enforces the 2KB alignment:
[...]
  [172] .bss.txFrameInfoArray_1.0 NOBITS          00000000 0012c0 000048 00  WA  0   0 64
  [173] .bss.txDataBuff_1.1 NOBITS          00000000 0012c0 001200 00  WA  0   0 64
  [176] .bss.txFrameInfoArray_0.4 NOBITS          00000000 0012c0 000048 00  WA  0   0 64
  [177] .bss.txDataBuff_0.5 NOBITS          00000000 0012c0 001200 00  WA  0   0 64
  [121] .bss._dcd_data    NOBITS          00000000 001800 000600 00  WA  0   0 2048


@artlessnoise I've edited the answer, take a look at it. Anyway in awk NF is the number of fields, so $NF is the last field

Now you see _dcd_data has alignment of 2k.  This rings of Freescale/NXP (you didn't mention) and the DCD can have alignment restrictions as it is run before the device boots.  It is weird it is in BSS as I thought this was a boot configuration table, but maybe it is something different in your system.  You need to investigate what dcd_data is.  Also, your assumption the compiler decided seems wrong; a misconception I mainly wanted to dispell.  For Freescale/NXP BSPs, DCD is often defined in linker scripts or assembler (but could be in 'C' code).

@artlessnoise although you are right that I use NXP microcontrollers, this particular variable is defined in the tinyusb sources. Take a look here: https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb_src/blob/main/src/portable/chipidea/ci_hs/dcd_ci_hs.c#L178

Sorry, it is a different DCD (USB Device Controller Driver vs Device configuration data).  I don't know about Kinetis USB.  Just got confused recently  by an FBGA FPGA :)

Input objects can have alignment constraints. The linker will pick the largest of the linker script or an input object.
